# Como hacer que una tabla se relacione con otra en Moongose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Se qué MongoDb no es relacional pero me pregunto que se debería hacer en mongo para lo siguiente: estoy aprendiendo a construir una bbdd para una aplicación que consiste en almacenar tests y por cada pregunta quiero que se almacenen 4 posibles respuestas. Entonces si mi Schema de `pregunta` es así de simple:

```js
const PreguntaSchema = new Schema({
    pregunta: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir una pregunta']
    }
});

const Pregunta = mongoose.model('pregunta', PreguntaSchema)
```

Como puedo hacer que cada 4 respuestas se relacionen con una pregunta en concreto en `respuestas` ?

```js
const RespuestasSchema = new Schema({
    respuestas: {
        respuesta_uno: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'debes escribir todas las opciones posibles'],
            correcta: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        respuesta_dos: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'debes escribir todas las opciones posibles'],
            correcta: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        respuesta_tres: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'debes escribir todas las opciones posibles'],
            correcta: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        respuesta_cuatro: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'debes escribir todas las opciones posibles'],
            correcta: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
    }
})

const Respuestas = moongose.model('respuestas', RespuestasSchema)
```

En la documentación de mongo pone que debería poner en mi Schema de `respuestas` algo así:

```
preguntas_id: <ObjectId1>
```

Entonces imagino que debería poner eso en cada respuesta (respuesta_uno, respuesta_dos...etc), ¿estoy en lo correcto?

He probado a ponerlo y me da error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una aproximacion es esta:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

const RespuestasSchema = new Schema({
  respuestas: {
    respuesta_uno: {
      pregunta: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "pregunta",
        required: [true, "El pregunta es necesario"]
      },
      correcta: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },
    respuesta_dos: {
      pregunta: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "pregunta",
        required: [true, "El pregunta es necesario"]
      },
      correcta: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },
    respuesta_tres: {
      pregunta: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "pregunta",
        required: [true, "El pregunta es necesario"]
      },
      correcta: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },
    respuesta_cuatro: {
      pregunta: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "pregunta",
        required: [true, "El pregunta es necesario"]
      },
      correcta: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

*** OPCIONES PARA MEJORAR ESTRUCTURA Y CLARIDAD ***

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

const RespuestasSchema = new Schema({
  respuestas: {
    respuesta_uno: PreguntaGrupoSchema,
    respuesta_dos: PreguntaGrupoSchema,
    respuesta_tres: PreguntaGrupoSchema,
    respuesta_cuatro: PreguntaGrupoSchema
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('respuesta', PreguntaSchema)
```

```
const PreguntaGrupoSchema = new Schema({
  pregunta: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      //Este tiene que ser como definiste el model
      // para que la relacion y la validacion se puedan
      // hacer. En realidad en este campo solo se guardara un 
      // id
    ref: "pregunta",
    required: [true, "la pregunta es necesario"]
  },
  correcta: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})
```

```
module.exports = PreguntaGrupoSchema

const PreguntaSchema = new Schema({
    pregunta: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir una pregunta']
    }
});

exports.module = mongoose.model('pregunta', PreguntaSchema)
```